Images won't load in Next.js 14.0.2 app after deploying to Vercel
I am learning nextjs at https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app
and I reached the end, but now that I have deployed my application, I see that the images are not loading, but they were loading while on my local machine:
Localhost:

Vercel deployment:

i used import Image from 'next/image';
this is how I implemented it:

the folders where the images are:

my next.config.js file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = nextConfig;

I am also using middleware for authentication. :
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|_next/public|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};


I have tried changing the image path in the following ways:
 <Image src="/hero-desktop.png"/>
 <Image src="./hero-desktop.png"/>
 <Image src="/public/hero-desktop.png"/>
 <Image src="./public/hero-desktop.png"/>

//or putting the image in a subfolder:
 <Image src="/static/hero-desktop.png"/>

and nothing seems to work, what do I do? Why is this happening?
I have seen all the similar questions.

Images should be in the images folders inside the public folder in the root folder.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
